# Django query is slow, optimize

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, django, optimization

```
def search(request):
    found_entries = None
    query = Q(feedstock__fs_name__icontains=corn
    found_entries = Sample.objects.filter(query).exclude(status_id=3).order_by('id')
    queries = request.GET.copy()
    sample = paging(request, found_entries)
    return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'sample': sample, 'queries': queries},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This returns about 9000 entries, it takes a very long time to query. And for the paging, if you click next page, it takes just as long, as if its re-querying the data. Any ideas on how to speed up the query or optimizing it?

Comment: Whats the size of the `Sample` table you are querying against?

Comment: Sample table has 18000 entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Django pagination to set the result size? If not I'd say take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/

Here's the long and short of the Doc as it pertains to you:

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```